Adding Conditional HTML Ending and Opening Tags in .NET 8 Blazor Page
I am trying to find out what the recommended approach is for adding conditional closing and opening tags HTML into a .NET 8 Blazor Page such as to equally split up database records into 3 <div class="col-md"></div> tags when outputted on the page in this case to display a restaurant menu.
The motivation for this is to display records alphabetically downwards in a table with the name and price and then across the page rather than across the page first as you would get if all were just put into separate bootstrap <div class="col-md-x"></div> tags.
This is in order to resemble a food menu.
I am updating the code from some existing JavaScript where the records are divided by 3 to get the number required in each row and then  </div><div class="col-md"> is conditionally inserted to break the content at that point and reset the count but with .NET, it checks the order of HTML tags in the code and thinks this will result in an error so the compiler states RZ9981: Unexpected closing tag 'div' with no matching start tag.
However when outputted on the page, as it is closing and then re-opening the tag in the foreach loop the resulting HTML would be valid but the page will not compile.
I have tried various techniques such as using tag helpers or using @: but none of the solutions given seem to work, at least in more recent versions of .NET. Using @: does output extra tags but they appear inside the tag I am trying to close so it doesn't display as intended.
In the end I ended up splitting the ICollection from the database into 3 ICollections and then iterating through all 3 in separate div tags which has worked in this instance but seems a bit repetitive and would not work if the number of columns could change as this is hard-coded.
This is what worked but doesn't seem ideal:
int numItems = cat.MenuItem.Count;
int numItemsPerCol = (int)Math.Round((decimal)((decimal)numItems / 3));

@* Split into 3 lists of records  *@
ICollection<MenuItem> col1Items = cat.MenuItem.Take(numItemsPerCol).ToList();
ICollection<MenuItem> col2Items = cat.MenuItem.Skip(numItemsPerCol).Take(numItemsPerCol).ToList();
ICollection<MenuItem> col3Items = cat.MenuItem.Skip(numItemsPerCol * 2).ToList();

<div class="col-md">
@foreach (var item in col1Items)
{

}
</div>

<div class="col-md">
@foreach (var item in col2Items)
{

}
</div>

<div class="col-md">
@foreach (var item in col3Items)
{

}
</div>

Surely there must be a better way than this?

I wouldn't use this kind of manual sledge-hammer to force the data to a form factor, unless you have a crucial reason for doing so.  I'd stick with simple CSS, with a media query to set the number of columns.  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

a better way than this? yes - there's no reason to make that calculation at all. Bootstrap itself decides how to display values based on col-... attributes. The developer (ie you) specify how you want items to appear in different resolutions with col-md-3, col-xs-12 etc attributes and bootstrap takes care of using a different number of columns for different resolutions. What you try to do now is essentially the same as rendering everything as a single list with col-3

If you want to display menus as a wrapping list of cards you can do it using a Card whose width is specified by col-x and the size you want for each resolution

If the question is how to show list items in 3 columns check the duplicate. The layout is controlled by Bootstrap, not ASP.NET Core and col-md is a Bootstrap directive saying a div should take 1 column in a virtual 12-column grid for medium resolution devices. The answers in the duplicate show how to show list items in 2 columns instead using a bit of a hack, using style="column-count:2". You can use div instead of ul and li without affecting the result. The layout is provided by the CSS classes, not the tags

I understand how Bootstrap works with responsive columns and have used it since it first came out but what I am trying to achieve is to show elements going down and then across rather than across and filling down. If you think of a food menu you would have the items alphabetically downwards. Conditional closing tags are fine in JS which this was written in before being converted.

I don't think the question should be closed. Anyway, try using @foreach (var chunk in items.Chunk(numItems/3)) and then @foreach (var item in chunk)

Just to build a simple menu (based on what I understood from your request), I would go with a simpler approach like this:
    @code
    {

        ICollection<string> colItems = new List<string>() { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD","EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL","MMM"};

        int numItems = 12;
        int numItemsPerCol = 3;
    }


    @for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {

        @if (i % numItemsPerCol == 0)
        {
            <div class="col-md">            
                @for (int j = i; j < i+numItemsPerCol; j++)
                    @colItems.ElementAt(j)                 
            </div>
        }   
    }

I have used a general case because was much easy to test, but you can adapt it based on your needs. I hope this solution will help u.

Thanks this looks like it may work. I will give it a go

It's the Razor compiler that's giving you that error. To write this using raw html in the way you did in JS, you can revert to using the RenderTreeBuilder to write raw markup with standard C# logic code.
Something like this:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="row">
    @Content
</div>

@code{
    private int _cols = 3;
    private List<int> _list = Enumerable.Range(1, 22).Select(index => index).ToList();
    private int _itemsPerCol => (int)Math.Round((decimal)((decimal)(_list.Count()) / _cols));

    private RenderFragment Content => builder =>
    {
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        builder.AddMarkupContent(0, $"""<div class="col">""");
        while (x < _list.Count())
        {
            if(y > _itemsPerCol)
            {
                builder.AddMarkupContent(1, $"""</div><div class="col">""");
                y = 0;
            }
            builder.AddMarkupContent(2, $"""{_list[x]}<br />""");
            x++;
            y++;
        }
        builder.AddMarkupContent(3, $"""</div>""");
    };
}

Note that this is not the best way to address this problem, you should consider a more structured approach.

There's no reason to generate HTML manually. The compiler complains about the comment, not the actual code. This code is far more complicated, error prone and open to injection. It probably won't work either because Bootstrap ignores <br>. Column breaks require special styling

@PanagiotisKanavos - All true, but I simply demonstrated how to do it the way the OP suggested.  I'm sure the JS solution has all the same flaws.  And yes there are far more structured ways to do this, but you would need more information than provided in the question to answer the question properly.

This isn't a JS solution, it's raw HTML generation and probably doesn't work. br is simply wrong, whether you intend to use it to split columns or generate list items. There are appropriate tags for this like <li>  or <div>. If the OP wants to display restaurant menu items, each value isn't just a string bug a Card with bold text, prices and possibly an image

Thanks all for the ideas. I can see this looks like it would replicate what I was able to do in JS but realise it may not be the most straightforward way to approach this. I was trying to quickly get it up and running by converting the JS into C# and ran into this issue which was slowing me down so good to have a quick approach to at least get it to compile.
